# How to make an inline element appear on new line, or block element not occupy the whole line?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to do this with CSS. If I just use a `<br>` tag, it works flawlessly, but I'm trying to avoid doing that for obvious reasons.

Basically, I just want the `.feature_desc` `span` to start on a new line, but:

- If I make it an inline element, it won't have a line-break.
- If I make it a block element, it will expand to fit the entire line, putting each of these icons on its own line, and wasting tons of space on the screen (each `.feature_wrapper` will be a slightly different size, but none will ever be as wide as the entire screen.)

Example code: This works, but uses a `br` tag:

```
<li class='feature_wrapper' id='feature_icon_getstart'> 
    <span style='display: none;' class='search_keywords'>started</span> 
    <span class='feature_icon spriteicon_img' id='icon-getstart'><a href='getstarted/index.html' class='overlay_link'></a></span><br/>
    <span class='feature_desc'><a href='getstarted/index.html' >Getting Started Wizard</a></span> 
</li>
```

I want to style this with CSS to achieve the same result:

```
<li class='feature_wrapper' id='feature_icon_getstart'> 
    <span style='display: none;' class='search_keywords'>started</span> 
    <span class='feature_icon spriteicon_img' id='icon-getstart'><a href='getstarted/index.html' class='overlay_link'></a></span>
    <span class='feature_desc'><a href='getstarted/index.html' >Getting Started Wizard</a></span> 
</li>
```

Any ideas? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think you need to make a diagram or a screenshot to explain this.

Comment: Create a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net) for this for a better answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a flex parent works too.
Setting `flex-direction` to `column` will put each child on a new line and setting `align-items` will make them not take up the whole width.
Here is a small example:

```html
<div class="parent">
   <a>some links</a>
   <a>that should be on their own lines</a>
   <a>but not take up the whole parent width</a>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 111):

You can give it a property display block; so it will behave like a div and have its own line

CSS:

```
.feature_desc {
   display: block;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! AS it turns out, I just had an incorrect understanding of block elements work when within an inline-block element (made worse by IE7's incompatibility with modern CSS.)

Comment: a virtual -1 for that answer because it, yes, will make a new line, but the whole element will claim 100% width then, too; which might not be wanted.
The problem might be more obvious when considering an `a` tag being display:block. It will claim 100% and the whole "line" will be clickable then, not just the part where actual text is.

Comment: The OP explicitly says this is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 40):

Even though the question is quite fuzzy and the HTML snippet is quite limited, I suppose

```
.feature_desc {
    display: block;
}
.feature_desc:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

might give you want you want to achieve without the `<br/>` element. Though it would help to see your CSS applied to these elements.

NOTE. The example above doesn't work in IE7 though.

Comment: don't understand why this get so few votes... It's the best approach (see my comment on the Accepted Answer why)

Comment: You can skip the display:block part, since the code in the before handles the element moving to the next line. That worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I think floats may work best for you here, if you dont want the element to occupy the whole line, float it left should work.

```
.feature_wrapper span {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    display:inline
}
```

EDIT: now browsers have better support you can make use of the do inline-block.

```
.feature_wrapper span {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; *zoom:1;
}
```

Depending on the text-align this will appear as through its inline while also acting like a block element.

Answer (score 6):

For the block element does not occupy the whole line, set its width to something small and the `white-space:nowrap`

```css
label {
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: this should only work for text... not for block elements.

Answer (score 3):

[Forcing New Line / Line-Break Using Only CSS - Designcise](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-add-a-line-break-to-an-html-element-using-css-only)

```css
span::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: The easiest and the neatest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar situation on our WooCommerce site. The "Add to cart" button was right next to a custom product field, and I needed to drop the product field below the button. This is the CSS that ended up doing the trick for me

`#product-57310 label[for="wcj_product_input_fields_local_1"] { display: -webkit-box!important; margin-top: 80px; }`

where "#product-57310" is the ID of the product in woocommerce, so that it only applies to the specific product page and not every product page, and where "label[for="wcj_product_input_fields_local_1"]" is targeting the first label specifically to get under the "Add to cart" button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had something like this:

```
<span>
 <input>
 <label>
 <input>
 <label>
 ...
</span>
```

I didn't wanna mess with the source html generator (even tho this html is pretty bad). So the way I fixed it is use a `display: grid` on the top `span`. Then `grid-template-columns: auto auto;`

Anyone looking to do something similar, `grid` is a good solution now (in 2021).

For example, for this particular problem, applying
`display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto;` to `li` and `grid-column: 1 / 3;` to last `span` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use two CSS rules**

```
word-break: break-all;
display: list-item;
```

**inside of a CSS selector and body**

---

Note:

**If only dealing with text that needs to be put on separate lines.**

Try using `word-break` like so (note stack overflow code automatically does this but I included it to help clarify usage in other environments:

```
 word-break: break-all;
```

**If only dealing with in-line HTML elements like a `<span>`**

Then see this answer as to how to convert non text elements (like an anchor tag) to line separated elements using a `display: list-item` also on the html tag

Link

[How to make text in <a> tag wordwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336729/how-to-make-text-in-a-tag-wordwrap/24732115#24732115)

---

**Example (For HTML inline elements like span)**

```css
span {
  display: list-item;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<span>Line 1</span>
<span>Line 2</span>
<span>Line 3</span>
<span>Line 4</span>
<span>Line 5</span>
```

**Example (For Text Content)**

```js
function makePerson(name, age) {
    // add code here
    let person = Object.create({});
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    return person;
}

const person = makePerson('Vicky', 24);
const outputDiv = document.querySelectorAll("body .output");
const keys = Object.keys(person);

outputDiv.forEach((div,key) => {
    div.innerHTML = person[keys[key]];
});
```

```css
body #output{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="output"></div>
   <div class="output"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Injecting a Line Break | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/)

```css
.feature_desc span {
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<li class='feature_wrapper' id='feature_icon_getstart'> 
    <span style='display: none;' class='search_keywords'>started</span> 
    <span class='feature_icon spriteicon_img' id='icon-getstart'><a href='getstarted/index.html' class='overlay_link'></a></span><br/>
    <span class='feature_desc'><a href='getstarted/index.html' >Getting Started Wizard</a></span> 
</li>
```