# How to make text in <a> tag wordwrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make text in `<a>` tag fit in a fixed div, but it breaks the div and displays ugly.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a CSS3 property: `word-wrap: break-word`

Take a look at the [MDN word-wrap docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap) for more info.

Comment: is it possible to make for an anchor tag? I tried a lot but not getting word-wrap:break-word applied in  IE

Answer (score 17):

```css
pre {
      white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
      white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
      white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
      word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
      width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<pre><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

I got solution by using display:block in

```
a{
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            word-break: break-all;
            white-space: normal;
            display:block;

 }
```

It worked for me in IE

Comment: you have redundant "white-space" which means only the second "white-space: normal;" gets applied

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution to make `word-wrap: break-word` effective for Anchor tag in IE by setting the `display:list-item` of the Anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap text in **a tag** through the below css.

```
a {

  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

[image][image]